# Require file for mount and also update the file after mount?

Tags: puppet

I am trying to make sure a directory exists for a mount and then also update the permissions of that directory after the mount happens. I am receiving the following error:

`err: Failed to apply catalog: Cannot alias File[pre_eos_mount] to ["/var/tmp/eos"] at /etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/eos.pp:29; resource ["File", "/var/tmp/eos"] already declared at /etc/puppet/modules/mymodule/manifests/eos.pp:47`

I would like to do something like this:

```
file { $eos_mount :
    ensure  => 'directory',
    mode    => '1777',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
  }

  mount { $eos_mount :
    ensure  => 'mounted',
    device  => $lv_device,
    fstype  => $fstype,
    options => 'defaults,noatime,nodiratime',
    require => File[$eos_mount],
    notify  => File['post_eos'],
  }

  file { 'post_eos' :
    path    => $eos_mount,
    ensure  => 'directory',
    mode    => '1777',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
  }
```

What is a way to ensure permissions of a folder after it has been mounted?

Comment: Could you 'cheat' and just setup an `exec` resource with a command of `mkdir -p $eos_mount`, which would just create the directory if it didn't already exist?

Comment: I guess. But that seems like a cheap way out. I'll give it a try though, especially since the first creation of it doesn't matter much since the permissions part is more important after it is mounted.

Comment: `exec` is a hack, but it's the only way to do it besides running Puppet multiple times. Puppet doesn't provide a way to apply the same resource from the catalog multiple times, even in different run stages.

Comment: I wonder if this could be achieved by the stdlib anchor class - http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib

Answer (score 0):

In puppet 3+ you can modify an existing resource like so:

See the documentation [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_resources.html#adding-or-modifying-attributes) for more details

```
file { $eos_mount :
  ensure  => 'directory',
  mode    => '1777',
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
}

mount { $eos_mount :
  ensure  => 'mounted',
  device  => $lv_device,
  fstype  => $fstype,
  options => 'defaults,noatime,nodiratime',
  require => File[$eos_mount],
  notify  => File['post_eos'],
}

File[$eos_mount] {
  path    => $eos_mount,
  ensure  => 'directory',
  mode    => '1777',
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I never noticed that par tof the docs before. New as of Puppet 3.x? I'll give it a try in a couple days once I get back into this part of my Puppet code.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally wrong for the question. Your second declaration is identical to the first, which is allowed. But declarations of existing resources may not remove existing attributes or change their values (unless overriding default ones). Further, a second declaration does not alter the _timing_ of the resource's creation. So if this works, it's a coin-toss.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use the module: [puppet-name_service_lookups](https://github.com/wcooley/puppet-name_service_lookups) and do something like:

```
$user_info = getpwnam($owner) 
$user_uid = $user_info['uid'] 
$group_info = getgrnam($group) 
$group_gid = $group_info['gid']
```

and in the options for mount, do:

```
options => "defaults,noatime,nodiratime,uid=${user_uid},gid=${group_gid}",
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand from the error the problem is that you already defined the resource `file {'/var/tmp/eos': }` somewhere before so puppet master won't let you compile the catalog,  because a resource has to be unique (resource type + $name).

In such a case when you have a potential conflict of same resources you should use [virtual resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/2.7/reference/lang_virtual.html), which guarantee that it's only added once in the catalog, regardless how many time you include it.

Comment: You appear to have read the error message and paid absolutely no attention to what the OP is actually trying to do.